# Different body for same Curl request sent from Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, curl

I'm trying to send a curl request from both Windows and Ubuntu system to a Rest API. following is the request

```
curl -k -X POST  http://172.16.76.1:8080/test -d 'sample_param={"user_info":{"name":"abc","age":"20"}}'
```

When I read this from the server side, I get the following two different content data from each OS

Body for curl request from Ubuntu:

```
sample_param={"user_info":{"name":"abc","age":"20"}}
```

Body for curl request from Windows:

```
sample_param={user_info:{name:abc,age:20}}
```

(Note that double quotations are missing)

As a result I cannot get the json object from the request.

Can someone point out the mistake and give a solution for this. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Changing the curl command to following worked

```
curl -k -X POST http://172.16.76.1:8080/test -d "sample_param={\"user_info\":{\"name\":\"abc\",\"age\":\"20\"}}"
```